# When the prompt() method is used to initialize a variable in javascript, what will the type of the initialized variable be?

Tags: javascript, prompt

I came across this problem/question while messing around in Codecademy's intro javascript tutorial.

For the following line of code, if I typed in the integer 5 (without inverted commas) upon being prompted by the pop-up box, what type will variable x end up being? 
Similarly, if I typed in "happiness" or "182" (with inverted commas), what will the type of variable x be?

Code:
var x = prompt("Type in a number from 1 to 10");

Summary:
Input: 5; what will be the type of x?
Input:"happiness"; what will be the type of x?
Input: "182"; what will be the type of x?

Answer (score 1):

The result will be a string type, in all cases unless the user cancels the prompt (in which case it will be `null`).

> `result` is a string containing the text entered by the user, or the value null.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.prompt

Answer (score 1):

They will all be strings or null if it is cancelled .You can use string functions on them. For mathematical calculations you will need to parse it.

Why don't you try those examples out yourself?

Comment: `or null if it is blank or cancelled` - wrong. If the field was blank, then a blank string will be returned.

Comment: oh yes , i forgot that in js , an empty string is not null. I have editted my answer